# google.maps.places.Autocomplete language output

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am using google.maps.places.Autocomplete object and always get results in Ukrainian language.

I am loading library like that

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=ru-RU

how to pass parameters to autocomplete language?

```
   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#google_places_ac")[0], {});
           google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
               var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
               $scope.location = place.formatted_address;
               // at that point $scope.location is in ukrainen, but I want Russian
               $scope.$apply();
            });
```

I've added image explains the problem. Text that squared with RED - is on Russian, text with Green - is on Ukraine. As you can see there is two different languages on the same map. Also input with Russian, and formatted language with Ukrainian. I believe this is a bug of Google map.s

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According Docs

> "The API detects the browser settings of the user and set the language appropriately. It is possible to override the language in the APIs."

That means, that the input will change according user language on the browser

try on the script tag.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=yourLanguage"></script>
```

take a look at this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) of languages

Edit:

Try setting this on language parameter

```
language=ru-RU
```

Comment: My brouser language is English. And when I get one results in Ukrainian, all next results are in Ukrainian too.

Comment: well thats a weird issue, test it on other browsers, currently im testing the code, with russian languaje (i don't understand anything im mexican), and its working like a charm, so i guess is a browser issue, not code issue

Comment: No. I noticed this strange behavior probably because of wrong using of Autocomplete object. When I start typing address in input field and then press one of proposed locations, immediately after that this proposed locations goes instead of my entered text on Russian language, that it is fine and what I need. But inside  google.maps.event listener, autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_location returns the same physical address but in Ukrainian language. Off course I can take text from this input directly using Jquery, what is also fine for me.

Comment: But now I faced with another problem how the get exact city from that location, because city could have any place in that string and in components array of

Comment: how about reproduce it on a JSfiddle?

Comment: I've added an image, now you can see what I mean

Comment: This expected language is the commonly used IETF language tag format. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag

Comment: Is this still valid? Im testing locally and am unable to enforce language using this method

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried *language=ru* instead of *language=ru-RU*? 
This works for me. For example, you can input address to Autocomplete in any supportable language, but autocomplete.getPlace() will return result in language from parameter and in case of Russian only *ru* works.

Have a look also at table of languages: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport

There is no *ru-RU*, only *ru*.