# Customize Google Places autocomplete pac-item text

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, google-places

I would like to know how could I customize the default Google Places Autocomplete text shown when user types on a autocomplete-enabled input (".pac-item" elements).

Specifically, I want to use portuguese language on my results, but even when I specify pt-BR language on autocomplete instantiation results are shown in english (e.g. "State of", "Brazil" ):

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                 (document.getElementById('city_settings')),
                 { language: "pt-BR", types: ['(cities)'], componentRestrictions : { country: 'br' } });
```

Any thoughts on how could I activate portuguese responses or how could I programatically edit those texts?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the language in the API call while loading the library

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*yourkey*&libraries=places&language=en
```

See also:

[google.maps.places.Autocomplete language output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130114/google-maps-places-autocomplete-language-output)